# Proof regarding congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I am studying for a Number Theory exam and this is one of the problems regarding congruence:

Prove that if ca ≡ cb (mod n), then a ≡ b (mod n/d), where d =gcd(c, n).

I am at a complete loss as to how to tackle this proof, and proofs have always been my weaker suit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with defintions...  $ca=cb\pmod n \implies  ca = cb + kn$  now what does $d=\gcd (c,n)$ mean?

Comment: Hmm, I notice that, if d=gcd(c,n), then c = dx and n = dy for some x and y.

Comment: More useful in this case, there exists $x,y$ pair in the set of integers such that $cx + ny = d$

Answer (score 1):

Back to basics. We have $c=c'd$ and $n=n'd$ with integers $c',n'$ such that $\gcd (n', c')=1.$ We have $\frac {ca-cb}{n}\in \Bbb Z$. So we have  $$\frac {c'(a-b)}{n'}=\frac {c'da-c'db}{n'd}=\frac {ca-cb}{n}\in \Bbb Z.$$ So $n'|c'(a-b)$ and $\gcd (n',c')=1,$ which implies $n'|(a-b).$

In other words $a\equiv b \pmod {n'}$ and $n'=n/d.$